# Скрипт JS | Не работает кнопка в меню скрипта, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, меню, скрипт

Создаю скрипт для форума, появилась проблема которую никак не могу решить тк-к новый в этом деле. К сути: Создал кнопку
`addButton(' ПЕРЕДАТЬ ', 'selectTransfer', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid;  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 213, 0.5);');`
Создал к ней меню, мне нужно при нажатии на определенный шаблон в меню выводить сообщение из `const transfer`  на которое я нажал, вот полный код:

```js
Выше инфа о скрипте

(function () {
  'use strict';
const UNACCEPT_PREFIX = 4; // Отказано
const ACCEPT_PREFIX = 8; // Принято
const RESHENO_PREFIX = 6; // Решено
const PIN_PREFIX = 2; // ЗАКРЕПИТЬ
const GA_PREFIX = 12; // ГА
const COMMAND_PREFIX = 10; // Команде проекта
const CLOSE_PREFIX = 7; // Закрыто
const VAJNO_PREFIX = 1; // Префикс ВАЖНО
const WATCHED_PREFIX = 9; // Префикс СМОТРЕНО
const TEX_PREFIX = 13; // Теху
const PREFIKS = 0;
const OTKAZRP_PREFIX = 4; // Отказ РП
const ODOBRENORP_PREFIX = 8; // Одобрено РП
const NARASSMOTRENIIRP_PREFIX = 2; // На рассмотрении
const NARASSMOTRENIIORG_PREFIX = 2; // На рассмотрении ОРГ
const buttons = [

{
      title: '| Неграмотно |',
      content:
         '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/vZ2f6V91/2.png[/img][/url]<br>' +
        '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/zX82rx2b/1.png[/img][/url]<br>' +
        "[B][CENTER][COLOR=#00FFFF][ICODE]{{ greeting }}, уважаемый {{ user.name }} [/ICODE][/COLOR][/CENTER][/B]<br><br>"+
        "[B][CENTER][COLOR=lavender] После тщательной проверки вашей РП Биографии - Выношу вердикт:<br>"+
         "[B][CENTER][COLOR=lavender][ISPOILER][COLOR=red]''Отказано, закрыто''[/COLOR][/ISPOILER]. <br><br>"+
         '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/zX82rx2b/1.png[/img][/url]<br>' +
         '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/BZM1VV8z/download-5.gif[/img][/url]<br>',
      prefix: UNACCEPT_PREFIX,
      status: false,
    },
];

const transfer = [
{
  title: '| ТЕХУ |',
  content:
    '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/vZ2f6V91/2.png[/img][/url]<br>' + // Это Блек раша
    '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/zX82rx2b/1.png[/img][/url]<br>' + // Это синий блек
    "[B][CENTER][COLOR=#00FFFF][ICODE]{{ greeting }}, уважаемый {{ user.name }} [/ICODE][/COLOR][/CENTER][/B]<br><br>"+
    "[B][CENTER][COLOR=lavender] Ваша жалоба переходит техническому специалисту! Ожидайте ответа от технического специалиста сервера.<br><br>" +
    "[B][CENTER][COLOR=lavender]Приятной игры на [COLOR=black]BLACK[/COLOR] [COLOR=RED]RUSSIA[/COLOR].<br><br>"+
    '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/zX82rx2b/1.png[/img][/url]<br>' + // Это синий блек
    '[CENTER][url=https://postimages.org/][img]https://i.postimg.cc/gcSnDLQF/download-4.gif[/img][/url]<br>', // На рассмотрении
  prefix: TEX_PREFIX,
  status: true,
},

];

$(document).ready(() => {
// Загрузка скрипта для обработки шаблонов
$('body').append('<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>');

// Добавление кнопок при загрузке страницы
  addButton('Одобрено', 'accepted', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid; border-color: rgb(110, 192, 113, 0.5);');
  addButton('Отказано', 'unaccept', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid; border-color: rgb(220, 89, 89, 0.5);');
  addButton('На рассмотрение', 'pin', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid; border-color: rgb(247, 255, 0, 0.5);');
  addButton('ТЕХУ', 'texy', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid; border-color: rgb(205, 0, 255, 0.5);');
  addButton(' ШАБЛОНЧИКИ ', 'selectAnswer', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid;  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 213, 0.5);');
  addButton(' ПЕРЕДАТЬ ', 'selectTransfer', 'border-radius: 13px; margin-right: 5px; border: 2px solid;  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 213, 0.5);');

// Поиск информации о теме
const threadData = getThreadData();

$('button#pin').click(() => editThreadData(PIN_PREFIX, true));
$('button#accepted').click(() => editThreadData(ACCEPT_PREFIX, false));
$('button#teamProject').click(() => editThreadData(COMMAND_PREFIX, true));
$('button#unaccept').click(() => editThreadData(UNACCEPT_PREFIX, false));
  $('button#Zakrito').click(() => editThreadData(UNACCEPT_PREFIX, false));
  $('button#texy').click(() => editThreadData(TEX_PREFIX, true));

$(`button#selectAnswer`).click(() => {
  XF.alert(buttonsMarkup(buttons), null, 'Выберите ответ:');
  buttons.forEach((btn, id) => {
    if(id > 1) {
      $(`button#answers-${id}`).click(() => pasteContent(id, threadData, true));
    } else {
      $(`button#answers-${id}`).click(() => pasteContent(id, threadData, false));
    }
  });
});

$(`button#selectTransfer`).click(() => {
  XF.alert(buttonsMarkup(transfer), null, 'Выберите ответ:');
  buttons.forEach((btn, id) => {
    if(id > 1) {
      $(`button#selectTransfer-${id}`).click(() => pasteContent(id, threadData, true));
    } else {
      $(`button#selectTransfer-${id}`).click(() => pasteContent(id, threadData, false));
    }
  });
});
});

function addButton(name, id, style) {
       $('.button--icon--reply').before(
`<button type="button" class="button--primary button rippleButton" id="${id}" style="${style}">${name}</button>`,
);
}
function addAnswers() {
  $('.button--icon--reply').after(`<button type="button" class="button--cta uix_quickReply--button button button--icon button--icon--write rippleButton" id="selectAnswer" style="oswald: 3px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 13px;">ОТВЕТЫ</button>`,
);
}

function addTransfers() {
  $('.button--icon--reply').after(`<button type="button" class="button--cta uix_quickReply--button button button--icon button--icon--write rippleButton" id="selectTransfer" style="oswald: 3px; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 13px;">ПЕРЕДАЧА</button>`,
);
}

function buttonsMarkup(buttons) {
return `<div class="select_answer">${buttons
.map(
(btn, i) =>
`<button id="answers-${i}" class="button--primary button ` +
`rippleButton" style="margin:4px; ${btn.dpstyle}"><span class="button-text">${btn.title}</span></button>`,
)
.join('')}</div>`;
}

function transferMarkup(transfer) {
      return `<div class="select_answer">${transfer
      .map(
      (btn, i) =>
      `<button id="transfer-${i}" class="button--primary button ` +
      `rippleButton" style="margin:4px; ${btn.dpstyle}"><span class="button-text">${btn.title}</span></button>`,
      )
      .join('')}</div>`;
      }

function pasteContent(id, data = {}, send = false) {
const template = Handlebars.compile(buttons[id].content);
if ($('.fr-element.fr-view p').text() === '') $('.fr-element.fr-view p').empty();

$('span.fr-placeholder').empty();
$('div.fr-element.fr-view p').append(template(data));
$('a.overlay-titleCloser').trigger('click');

if(send == true){
  editThreadData(buttons[id].prefix, buttons[id].status);
  $('.button--icon.button--icon--reply.rippleButton').trigger('click');
}
}
    

function getThreadData() {
const authorID = $('a.username')[0].attributes['data-user-id'].nodeValue;
const authorName = $('a.username').html();
const hours = new Date().getHours();
return {
user: {
id: authorID,
name: authorName,
mention: `[USER=${authorID}]${authorName}[/USER]`,
},
 greeting: () =>
      4 < hours && hours <= 11 ?
      'Доброе утро' :
      11 < hours && hours <= 15 ?
      'Добрый день' :
      15 < hours && hours <= 21 ?
      'Добрый вечер' :
      'Доброй ночи',
  };
}

function editThreadData(prefix, pin = false) {
// Получаем заголовок темы, так как он необходим при запросе
const threadTitle = $('.p-title-value')[0].lastChild.textContent;

if(pin == false){
  fetch(`${document.URL}edit`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: getFormData({
    prefix_id: prefix,
    title: threadTitle,
    _xfToken: XF.config.csrf,
    _xfRequestUri: document.URL.split(XF.config.url.fullBase)[1],
    _xfWithData: 1,
    _xfResponseType: 'json',
    }),
  }).then(() => location.reload());
}
if(pin == true){
  fetch(`${document.URL}edit`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: getFormData({
    prefix_id: prefix,
    title: threadTitle,
    sticky: 1,
    _xfToken: XF.config.csrf,
    _xfRequestUri: document.URL.split(XF.config.url.fullBase)[1],
    _xfWithData: 1,
    _xfResponseType: 'json',
    }),
  }).then(() => location.reload());
}
}

function getFormData(data) {
const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries(data).forEach(i => formData.append(i[0], i[1]));
return formData;
}
})();
```

Comment: Решено, уже все исправил